# "Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers" on update

Tags: mongodb

I get a "Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers" error while trying to update a field(s) in Mongo. An example:

```
> db.test.insert({test: "test1", array: [0]});
> var testFetch = db.test.findOne({test: "test1"});
> db.test.update(testFetch, 
                 {$push: {array: 1}, //push element to end of key "array"
                  $pop:  {array: -1} //pop element from the start of key "array"
                 });
  Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers
```

Is there no way to perform this atomic operation? I don't want to be doing two separate updates for this.

Comment: This was the first google result when I had this error. My issue, using mongoose, turned out to be this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1933

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an outstanding issue for this on Mongo's ticket system: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050

Looks like it's scheduled for this year. Your scenario is definitely a sensible scenario, but it's also tied to a bunch of edge cases. What if you `$push` and `$pop` on an empty array? What's expected? What do you want if you `$push` and `$pull`?

> I don't want to be doing two separate updates for this.

I know that doing this really has "code smell", but is it a complete blocker for using this solution? Is the "double-update" going to completely destroy server performance?

Comment: I've run into the same error. I think the "double-update" issue here is a serious problem though, given the nature of MongoDB's atomicity. If you have multiple applications that might update the same part of an array, you really don't want to $pull in one operation then $push in another...between the two some other process may have changed the same array element, which could result in bad/unexpected behavior.

Comment: I agree, there could definitely be data issues here. But it really depends on why you're doing this `$push / $pull`. In some cases you're just building a queue array and the order may not actually be *that* big a deal. Based on the JIRA ticket it's obviously a popular issue (*53 votes*), but it's also marked as minor and unscheduled. At the current rate of development this probably won't see the light of day for many months. That stated, for this to work you still need to iron out all of the edge cases.

Comment: I actually found a solution while trying to resolve concurrency issues. The latest versions of MongoDB support FindAndModify, and coupled with the array $ identifier (which represents the currently found array element), you can find and update a given array element of a document in a single operation that I believe is atomic.  At the very least, the operation completes successfully without error, and we have yet to encounter a concurrency issue. ;)

Comment: @jrista Can you post an example?

Comment: Actually, I believe it is possible to **update** array elements directly with just a standard update: `db.mycollection.update( { myarray : { $elemMatch : { someproperty : { $in : { "a", "b", "c" } } } } }, { $set : { 'myarray.$.otherproperty' : 567 } } );` As for doing a push/pop/pull concurrently on an array at the same time in a single atomic statement (which was actually what the original question asked for), I have not actually tried that explicit task (I  don't think I read the question the same way the first time.) I think FindAndModify would be the better way, though...